# Office365, Windows 10 enterprise, unable to open calendar from the internet

Tags: group-policy, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, icalendar

User on Win 10 laptop (64 bit Enterprise) with Office365.
**Route**:Outlook, Open Calendar, From Internet, Enter Location

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en-gb.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

Generates the error message:

"You cannot use Internet Calendar Subscriptions. Your system administrator has turned off this feature."

(Same error for any .ics file)

Answer (score 0):

2 policies that affected the registry.  A colleague's Windows 8.1 laptop did not have these policies and was able to link to the .ics file.

Using regedit found these:

..Software,Policy,Office,16.0,Outlook,DisablePST (REG_DWORD), value 1 ..Software,Policy,Office,16.0,Outlook,Options,webcal (REG_DWORD),Disable value 1

To prove this was the problem I added 2 entries to the registry

..Software,Microsoft,Office,16.0,Outlook,DisablePST (REG_DWORD), value 0 ..Software,Microsoft,Office,16.0,Outlook,Options,webcal (REG_DWORD),Disable value 0

I was then able to add an internet calendar as expected.
This added a pst file to "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook"